# Psycopg2 on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, psycopg2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying upload my project (in python) that uses Psycopg2  for Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. I'm doing this with a zip file containing my project and an requirements.txt file.

But I'm receiving this error:

> Downloading/unpacking psycopg2>=2.4.6 (from -r
>   /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 3))   Running setup.py
>   egg_info for package psycopg2
>       Error: pg_config executable not found.
>
> ```
> Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
> or specify the full executable path with the option:
>
>     python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
>
> or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
> Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
> running egg_info
> ```

How can I solve this on Amazon?

Comment: What does your requirements.txt file look like?

Comment: My requirements.txt is: 
tornado>=2.0.0
httplib2>=0.8
psycopg2>=2.4.6

Comment: What happens if you run `which pg_config`?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Need postgresql-devel in your container.
Create a file '.ebextensions/packages.config' with the contents:

```
packages:
  yum:
    postgresql94-devel: []
```

Replace `94` in `postgresql94-devel` with whatever version of postgres you need. For example, `postgresql93-devel` for postgres 9.3.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-packages

Comment: I'm getting error saying "Yum doesn't have postgresql-devel".

Comment: Try postgresql94-devel or whatever version your instance needs. eb ssh onto the instance and use `yum list installed` to check what version of postgres is installed.

Comment: Postgresql 9.4 in Amazon Linux is available since version 2015.09. Update Amazon Linux first and then don't forget to rebuild environment.

Comment: Do you need to commit this file in your git repo?

Comment: You might need to run `yum search postgresql` to find the version if you don't have postgres installed.

Answer (score 20):

Tried to comment on the accepted answer but don't have the reputation to do so.  Recent forum posts from AWS support indicate that the package name is "postgresql93-devel".  postgresql-devel does not work in the 2014.09 AMIs.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled for a while with and couldn't get the above solution to work. I tried many other solutions as well, but it ended up being a lack of fundamental understanding on my part.

The config files are read alphabetically. So if you have more than one, which you likely do, make sure that 'packages.config' comes alphabetically before your .config with container_commands.

Otherwise 'syncdb' for example will be called before your packages have been installed.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sudo yum install gcc python-setuptools python-devel postgresql-devel
sudo easy_install psycopg2
```

This worked perfectly on my Linux AWS