# psycopg2 on elastic beanstalk - can't deploy app

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying my first app(Flask) to EB and am hitting a snag. Using PostgreSQL requires that I get psycopg2 installed but I can't figure out how to get it running.

I saw in this post ([Psycopg2 on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137346/psycopg2-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk)) as well as this post(https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/) that I need to add a file name `.elasticbeanstalk/01_packages.config` with the following code:

```
packages:
  yum:
    postgresql-devel: []
```

I've tried different variations with `postgresql93-devel: []` and still no luck. Attached below are my error logs.

```
[2015-11-16T21:03:24.749Z] INFO  [2680]  - [Application update/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03deploy.py] : Starting activity...
[2015-11-16T21:03:27.024Z] INFO  [2680]  - [Application update/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03deploy.py] : Activity execution failed, because: Collecting psycopg2==2.6.1 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
    Using cached psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      running egg_info
      creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
      writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

      Error: pg_config executable not found.

      Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
      or specify the full executable path with the option:

          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

      ----------------------------------------
  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-z20gvx7_/psycopg2
  2015-11-16 21:03:27,010 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: Collecting psycopg2==2.6.1 (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
    Using cached psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz
      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
      running egg_info
      creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
      writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

      Error: pg_config executable not found.

      Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
      or specify the full executable path with the option:

          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

      ----------------------------------------
  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-z20gvx7_/psycopg2
  2015-11-16 21:03:27,010 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

It seems pretty clear that I need to get psycopg2 installed but I'm not sure what other steps I can take to make this work.

Comment: I have the same. I'll let you know if I solve it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I solved it, you need to open you EC2 instance first, then install like this

```
sudo yum install postgresql-devel
```

Then deploy your EB

Comment: was able to complete `sudo install psycopg2` only after the command you provided!

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering, if we have multiple ec2 instances when using EB, do we need to run this command on each isntance?

Comment: This does not solve the problem. If you have more instances, or when the instance is replaced then this would fail again

Answer (score 15):

Funny enough, the solution for me for **Amazon Linux 2** ended up being what the original question was -
adding a `01_package.conf` with the contents of

```
packages:
  yum:
    postgresql-devel: []
```

Furthmore, this was contrary to almost all answers I found online which directed to use `postgresql96-devel` or some other number. I found out I needed to make the package name `postgresql-devel` *after* SSHing onto the EC2 instance and viewing all available Yum packages.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ~]$ yum list available | grep 'postgresql'
freeradius-postgresql.x86_64           3.0.13-10.amzn2                amzn2-core
pcp-pmda-postgresql.x86_64             3.12.2-5.amzn2                 amzn2-core
postgresql.x86_64                      10.4-5.amzn2.0.2               amzn2extra-postgresql10
postgresql-contrib.x86_64              10.4-5.amzn2.0.2               amzn2extra-postgresql10
postgresql-devel.x86_64                10.4-5.amzn2.0.2               @amzn2extra-postgresql10
postgresql-docs.x86_64                 10.4-5.amzn2.0.2               amzn2extra-postgresql10
...
```

and I saw it was just `postgres-devel`. Once I changed it to that it deployed alright. Make sure you commit your change if you're using `eb` with git before running `eb deploy` - or at least add the changes to your git staging area and run with `eb deploy --staged` as well. That one cost me a run around thinking I had already tried the package name when I hadn't

I found the [answers on this stackoverflow post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55798856/deploy-postgres11-to-elastic-beanstalk-requires-etc-redhat-release) to be helpful as well. Good luck!

---

I ended up needing a newer `psql` client (`11.x`) than what was default using the above answer (`9.2` at the time of posting). [This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63204453/5180047) was the only way I could make it work. Answer pasted here for posterity...

```
packages:
    yum:
        amazon-linux-extras: []

commands:
    01_postgres_activate:
        command: sudo amazon-linux-extras enable postgresql11
    02_postgres_install:
        command: sudo yum install -y postgresql-devel
```

Comment: Your comment solved the issue for me, you're amazing. For others out there using Amazon Linux 2 - this is the solution.

Comment: thank you  this one gave me a lot of trouble - especially since most documentation says to use `postgresql96-devel` (including AWS's) or some other version... even put up a bounty without luck. Glad my efforts helped someone else!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Took a long time to figure out that the version number was messing my deployment, specially when so many tutorials point to a postgresql with a version

Comment: What is 11 at the end of `postgresql11`? Should I use 12 instead if I try to connect to RDS with postgres 12.5?

Comment: I think you may be out of luck unless you want to build it yourself. If you speak with support staff please comment out. I checked on AL2 with `amazon-linux-extras list | grep 'postgres'` and only see 9.6, 10, and 11. I remember having a hell of a time getting elastic beanstalk going... good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Even after installing postgresql93-devel, I kept getting an error "no module named psycopg2". To solve this I had to connect to my enviroment with eb ssh and then execute `sudo pip install psycopg2` to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You mis-named the directory.  Config files go in the `.ebextensions` directory, you have yours in the `.elasticbeanstalk` directory.  That won't work.  Try:

```
mkdir .ebextensions && mv .elasticbeanstalk/01_packages.config .ebextensions
```

Then deploy your app again.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the issue by:
1.run : eb ssh
2. In the ec2 terminal run: sudo yum install -y postgresql-devel

redeploy your app. it should deploy without the error

Comment: Can you elaborate?