# Deploy Postgres11 to Elastic Beanstalk - Requires /etc/redhat-release

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having a hell of a time deploying my first app to Elastic Beanstalk and could really use some help. I cannot get Postgres11 to install though it is officially supported with RDS.

**ISSUE**
If I run `eb deploy` I get the message saying `pg_config` executable not found. It is required to build `psycopg2` from source.

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'project_urls'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running egg_info
creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

Error: pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
option: ...
```

I suppose I'll need to add the repo? Fair enough. Next I try adding the repo as I have found in other posts across the internet:

```
[ec2-user@ip-... etc]$ sudo yum -y install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos11-11-2.noarch.rpm
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
pgdg-centos11-11-2.noarch.rpm                                          | 5.6 kB  00:00:00     
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-cQJP_4/pgdg-centos11-11-2.noarch.rpm: pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-4.noarch
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-cQJP_4/pgdg-centos11-11-2.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package pgdg-redhat-repo.noarch 0:42.0-4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /etc/redhat-release for package: pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-4.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /etc/redhat-release for package: pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-4.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-4.noarch (/pgdg-centos11-11-2.noarch)
           Requires: /etc/redhat-release
```

**From here I'm *stuck*.** I've tried symlinking `/etc/system-release -> /etc/redhat-release` with no luck. Nobody else seems to have this problem? I also don't seem to have the coveted `amazon-linux-extras` for some reason?

### Environment

**Environment tier:** Web Server
**Platform:** Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.8.2

---

***.ebextensions/packages.config***

```
packages:
  yum:
    postgresql11-devel: []
```

***requirements.txt***

```
Django==2.2
psycopg2==2.8.2
pytz==2019.1
sqlparse==0.3.0
```

---

```
[ec2-user@ip-... etc]$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"

[ec2-user@ip-... etc]$ cat /etc/system-release 
Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03
```

Comment: I noticed that the `os-release` specified that `ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"`. I tried using the fedora rpm and the same result happend -> `Requires: /etc/fedora-release`

Comment: I would still love to know what I’m missing with this, but in order to move forward I’ve reverted back to PostgreSQL 9.6 because it’s readily available on EB/EC2.

Comment: When using the ordinary Amazon Linux 2 AMI you can issue the command: **amazon-linux-extras install postgresql10** to get version 10.

Comment: For those looking for postgres 12 https://qiita.com/tmiki/items/00d22edc6a554f61bd04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem with PostgreSQL 10 for a Django 2.1 project on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

The issue was introduced last week around 17 Apr 2019 to make sure the operating system is an actual Red Hat release (which Amazon Linux is not). I found some details on the PostgreSQL mailing list:

> "Amazon Linux support was removed years ago actually. I just made sure that our
>   repo file reflects that."
>   *([BUG #15768: Removed rpms and now require /etc/redhat-release](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/15768-35c3af8405f5e346%40postgresql.org))*

One poster on the mailing list suggested the following fix:

> "We have temporarily mitigated the issue by **using rpm and explicitly ignoring the repositories dependencies**, but that seems like a band-aid fix for the real problem which is that dependency shouldn’t be there."

Personally, I've done the same as you, Scott, I've simply reverted to the PostgreSQL 9.6 client packages that AWS supplies directly. As long as Django and psycopg support that release, this works fine.

However, the long-term fix is for AWS to finally provide platforms with Amazon Linux 2...

Comment: Thank you, goetz, for finding that insight. Looks like I just had some bad luck timing! I'll let them sort all that out first... :)

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you can build posgresql from source:

`wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v11.5/postgresql-11.5.tar.gz`

`tar zxvf postgresql-11.5.tar.gz`

`cd postgresql-11.5`

`./configure --without-readline`

`make`

`make install`

Comment: thanks, Using this I was able to upgrade my pg client to 12.4.

Comment: This just worked fine. You would also need to set the path.

export PATH=$PATH:binDirectoryPath

Comment: this is the way. I needed to install gcc make zlib-devel (all available via builtin yum repos on AL1), at least for PG13.5.

Comment: also can omit the `--without-readline` if you install `readline-devel` via yum, which turns out was rather useful

Answer (score 6):

PostgreSQL 11 is not yet available from Amazon but PostgreSQL 10 is. I'm using Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo) reported by `cat /etc/system-release`. To enable installation:

```
$ sudo amazon-linux-extras enable postgresql10
```

Once you enable this extra, you'll then see many packages for PostgreSQL 10 available through yum that can be installed normally:

```
$ yum list postgresql*
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Installed Packages
postgresql.x86_64                    10.4-5.amzn2.0.2    @amzn2extra-postgresql10
postgresql-devel.x86_64              10.4-5.amzn2.0.2    @amzn2extra-postgresql10
postgresql-libs.x86_64               10.4-5.amzn2.0.2    @amzn2extra-postgresql10
Available Packages
postgresql-contrib.x86_64            10.4-5.amzn2.0.2    amzn2extra-postgresql10
postgresql-docs.x86_64               10.4-5.amzn2.0.2    amzn2extra-postgresql10
postgresql-libs.i686                 10.4-5.amzn2.0.2    amzn2extra-postgresql10
postgresql-plperl.x86_64             10.4-5.amzn2.0.2    amzn2extra-postgresql10
postgresql-plpython.x86_64           10.4-5.amzn2.0.2    amzn2extra-postgresql10
postgresql-plpython3.x86_64          10.4-5.amzn2.0.2    amzn2extra-postgresql10
postgresql-pltcl.x86_64              10.4-5.amzn2.0.2    amzn2extra-postgresql10
postgresql-server.x86_64             10.4-5.amzn2.0.2    amzn2extra-postgresql10
postgresql-static.x86_64             10.4-5.amzn2.0.2    amzn2extra-postgresql10
postgresql-test.x86_64               10.4-5.amzn2.0.2    amzn2extra-postgresql10
postgresql-test-rpm-macros.x86_64    10.4-5.amzn2.0.2    amzn2extra-postgresql10
postgresql-upgrade.x86_64            10.4-5.amzn2.0.2    amzn2extra-postgresql10
postgresql-upgrade-devel.x86_64      10.4-5.amzn2.0.2    amzn2extra-postgresql10
```

Comment: I still don’t have amazon-linux-extras. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: @Scott, this is most likely because you (and I) are using Amazon Linux 1 on Elastic Beanstalk, whereas "amazon-linux-extras" appears to be an Amazon Linux 2 feature (https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/faqs/#Amazon_Linux_Extras, "Extras is a mechanism in Amazon Linux 2 to enable the consumption of new versions of application software on a stable operating system").

Comment: I updated my answer to note that yes I am on Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised that they offer PostgreSQL 10.6 and 11 in RDS, but don't have the matching packages for the driver available to install on their own Linux distro.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my maverick solution for the latest Amazon Linux 2 ami:

```
sudo su
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
nano pgdg.repo
```

Then I pasted this into the nano editor with its newly created pgdg.repo file:

```
[pgdg11]
name=PostgreSQL 11 $releasever - $basearch
baseurl=https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-7.5-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-PGDG-11
```

Further commands are:

```
sed -i "s/rhel-\$releasever-\$basearch/rhel-7.5-x86_64/g" "/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg.repo"
yum groupinstall "PostgreSQL Database Server 11 PGDG"
```

Create a new PostgreSQL database cluster:

```
/usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgresql-11-setup initdb
```

Now execute the following command to start and enable the postgresql services:

```
systemctl enable postgresql-11
systemctl start postgresql-11
```

Still, keep in mind the notes at this address: 
[Link to Postgresql.org](https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php#pg11)

Answer (score 0):

**What did not work for me:**

1. `Postgre10` and above is not available on `Amazon Linux 2`.
2. `Amazon-linux-extras` is not available on `(public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11)` python3.11 lambda image for Amazon Linux 2. So you cant use this library to install Postgres in `python3.11`  (`python3` more preferably) `lambda` image for `Amazon Linux 2`

**What worked for me:** (installing `postgres11` in `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11`), but underlying Linux is `Amazon Linux 2`, so applicable for all instances using AL2 - `EC2, Elastic Beanstalk` etc.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11.2023.08.02.09-x86_64
# install dependencies
RUN yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
RUN yum -y update
RUN echo -e "\
[pgdg11] \n\
name            = PostgreSQL 11 $releasever - $basearch \n\
baseurl         = https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-7.5-x86_64 \n\
enabled         = 1 \n\
gpgcheck        = 0 \n\
" > /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg.repo

RUN sed "s/rhel-\$releasever-\$basearch/rhel-7.5-x86_64/g" "/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg.repo"
RUN yum groupinstall "PostgreSQL Database Server 11 PGDG" -y
RUN yum install postgresql11 postgresql11-server -y
COPY systemctl.py /usr/bin/systemctl
RUN chmod a+x /usr/bin/systemctl
RUN systemctl enable postgresql11
RUN systemctl start postgresql11
RUN export PATH=/usr/pgsql-11/bin/psql:$PATH
```

Now you need to create a file called `systemctl.py` in the same directory as `Dockerfile` and copy the content in that from [here](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement/blob/master/files/docker/systemctl.py)

**Reference:** [this article](https://yogender027mae.medium.com/installing-postgres-11-on-python-3-11-29dae3574acd)

Answer (score 0):

Just use docker:

*sudo yum install docker*

*sudo systemctl start docker*

*sudo docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=admin -e  POSTGRES_PASSWORD=your_password -e POSTGRES_DB=virtual_office -p 5432:5432 -d postgres*

Once this is done. Go to your server:5432