# How to install PostgeSQL 11 on AWS Amazon Linux AMI 2?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, yum

I want to install PostgreSQL 11 on an EC2 instance, based on the Amazon Linux AMI 2 image. Following posts, SO questions, and [finding the latest Postgresl yum repository](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/), I tried:

```
sudo yum install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
```

I get this error:

```
--> Processing Dependency: /etc/redhat-release for package: pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-4.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-4.noarch (/pgdg-centos11-11-2.noarch)
           Requires: /etc/redhat-release
```

I'm stuck.. is there a clean way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Aman,

It may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55883490/7541412

Moreover, if you think PostgreSQL v10 can resolve your issues. You can try these commands:

> sudo yum update -y
>
> sudo amazon-linux-extras enable postgresql10

After having PostgreSQL in your repository, now you can install:

> yum clean metadata
>
> yum install postgresql

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but I need PostgreSQL 11 because it must be the same version for the client and the server (wich is 11). I will give a try to the post you're pointing at.

Comment: Thanks, the SO answer you pointed me to worked for me (almost).

Comment: Glad it helped you.

Comment: For those looking for Postgres 12 https://qiita.com/tmiki/items/00d22edc6a554f61bd04

Answer (score 16):

I successfully installed 11.5 on Amazon Linux using

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql11
```

Comment: How about 12.2? Is it available?

Comment: At least until now there is only 9.6 10 and 11

Comment: This command always installs psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.24

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with the Amazon Linux 2 AMI for CodeBuild using Python 3 but `amazon-linux-extras` only using Python 2 (totally bizarre considering Python 2 has been sunset, I know). From [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=310185) you can copy the `amazon_linux_extras` from the Python 2 `site-packages` to the Python 3 one.

To find the location of `amazon-linux-extras` use

```
find -type d -name "amazon_linux_extras"     # note the underscore (_), not dash (-)
```

To find the Python 3 `site-packages` directory

```
find -type d -name "site-packages"
```

To copy across

```
cp -r /path/to/amazon_linux_extras /path/to/python3/site-packages
```

Once I had done that, I used @Hassan's answer to upgrade to PostgreSQL 11.

Answer (score -3):

You can install PostgreSQL by running the following command:

`$ sudo yum install postgresql postgresql-server postgresql-devel postgresql-contrib postgresql-docs`

Out of curiosity why are you not using [PostgreSQL on AWS RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the above command doesn't work as postgresql is not in the repos supported by Amazon Linux AMI 2. This is why I need to add the repo first. I am already using AWS RDS for the server side, but I want to install the client on an EC2 instance, mainly to manage dumps.

Comment: @scandel I see. Try the instructions from this [blog](https://installvirtual.com/how-to-install-postgresql-11-on-amazon-ec2-amazon-linux/), see how it goes.

Comment: It's already what I did... just changed the repo with a more recent one (but also tried with the one in the blog post, with the same error).