# AWS EC2 Amazon Linux 2 AMI PostgreSQL Installation

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, postgresql-13, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

Have an AWS EC2 instance which is running `Amazon Linux AMI 2`.
Like to install `PostgreSQL Server 13` on it.
Following the instructions as mentioned here - https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/

But, when executing -

```
sudo yum install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
```

Getting bellow error -

```
sudo yum install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm                                                                                   | 8.1 kB  00:00:00     
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-TO1dIc/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm: pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-24.noarch
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-TO1dIc/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package pgdg-redhat-repo.noarch 0:42.0-24 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /etc/redhat-release for package: pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-24.noarch
amzn2-core                                                                                                           | 3.7 kB  00:00:00     
amzn2extra-docker                                                                                                    | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
amzn2extra-epel                                                                                                      | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
amzn2extra-java-openjdk11                                                                                            | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
amzn2extra-kernel-5.10                                                                                               | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
amzn2extra-postgresql13                                                                                              | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
epel/aarch64/metalink                                                                                                |  21 kB  00:00:00     
pgdg13                                                                                                               | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
(1/3): amzn2-core/2/aarch64/group_gz                                                                                 | 2.5 kB  00:00:00     
(2/3): amzn2-core/2/aarch64/updateinfo                                                                               | 473 kB  00:00:00     
(3/3): amzn2-core/2/aarch64/primary_db                                                                               |  45 MB  00:00:00     
194 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
--> Processing Dependency: /etc/redhat-release for package: pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-24.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-24.noarch (/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch)
           Requires: /etc/redhat-release
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: There is similar thread here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55798856/deploy-postgres11-to-elastic-beanstalk-requires-etc-redhat-release

Answer (score 9):

The normal way to setup postgresql 13 on Amazon Linux 2 is:

```
 sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql13
```

Comment: Thanks. I think - it got installed.

But, how to configure and start it?
Because I can not find "/usr/pgsql-13/bin/postgresql-13-setup" directory.

Comment: @CRSardar This is a new issue, thus new question should be asked.